# Avoid URL redirects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, yslow, google-pagespeed

when i checked the GTmetrix site in Yslow it has shown that i have few URL redirects which i need to avoid for increasing my site speed.
But i had URL redirects from

- `http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/viewthroughconversion/997898667/?...` redirects to `http://www.google.com/ads/user-lists/997898667/?...`
- `http://www.youtube.com/embed/XeyKZ4CVsWs` redirects to `https://www.youtube.com/embed/XeyKZ4CVsWs`
- `http://www.youtube.com/embed/SjoNhZhuaGc` redirects to `https://www.youtube.com/embed/SjoNhZhuaGc`

Youtube and googleads is there any possibility of avoiding these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the ads, the general answer is No. Redirects are very common there and there isn't much you can do.

For the embedded youtube.com content, you could explicitly include them with secure links "https://" instead of "http://". That might save you some redirect penalties.